# Can't fetch firebase collection with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks + firebase.

In firebase, I created a collection called "projects"

[image]

When I try to console log the data with:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { firebase } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {console.log(firebase.db.collection("projects"))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm getting the following object:

[image]

**Shouldn't be able to see my data?**

Below are my firebase and context set up

firebase.js

```
import app from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firebase-firestore";

const config = {//mydata}

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth();
    this.db = app.firestore();
  }
}

export default new Firebase();
```

context.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { projectReducer } from "./reducers";
import firebase from "../components/firebase/firebase";

export const GlobalState = props => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useReducer(projectReducer, []);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        projects,
        firebase
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key of how you interact with Firestore in your code seems to be:

```
firebase.db.collection("projects")
```

This code creates a reference to the `projects` collection in Firestore. It does **not** retrieve any data from the database yet.

To get data, you need to attach a listener to the collection. From the [Firestore documentation on getting documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection):

> ```
> db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
>     .get()
>     .then(function(querySnapshot) {
>         querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
>             // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
>             console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
>         });
>     })
>     .catch(function(error) {
>         console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
>     });
> ```

You'll need to do something similar in your code.

Typically in React projects, you'll store the data in the component's state by calling `setState(...)` in the `then()` callback, and then render the content from the state in your JSX.