# FireStore - Update the UI with new data without reloading the browser

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I use the following component to add new data in a Google Cloud FireStore collection:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const AddCard = ({ totalDoclNumbers }) => {
  const [newOriginalText, setNewOriginalText] = useState([]);
  const [newTranslatedText, setNewTranslatedText] = useState([]);
  const nextNumber = totalDoclNumbers + 1;

  const onAdd = async () => {
    await db.collection('FlashCards').add({
      originalText: newOriginalText,
      translatedText: newTranslatedText,
      customId: Number(nextNumber),
    });
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      <li key={nextNumber}>
        <input
          type='text'
          readOnly
          defaultValue={nextNumber}
        />
        <div>
            <textarea
              placeholder='English'
              onChange={(e) => setNewOriginalText(e.target.value)}
            />
        </div>
        <textarea
          placeholder='Translation'
          onChange={(e) => setNewTranslatedText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={onAdd}>
          Add
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

export default AddCard;

The add button works and I can see that new data are added to the collection on Google server, however to be able to see those new data, I have to refresh the page.

In order to fix it, I decided to make use of **onSnapshot** function as follow:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const AddCard = ({ totalDoclNumbers }) => {
  const [newOriginalText, setNewOriginalText] = useState([]);
  const [newTranslatedText, setNewTranslatedText] = useState([]);
  const nextNumber = totalDoclNumbers + 1;

  const onAdd = async () => {
    await db.collection('FlashCards').add({
      originalText: newOriginalText,
      translatedText: newTranslatedText,
      customId: Number(nextNumber),
    });
  };

  const renderDocList = () => {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li key={nextNumber}>
          <input
            type='text'
            defaultValue={nextNumber}
          />
          <div>
              <textarea
                placeholder='English'
                onChange={(e) => setNewOriginalText(e.target.value)}
              />
          </div>
          <textarea
            placeholder='Translation'
            onChange={(e) => setNewTranslatedText(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button onClick={onAdd}>
            Add
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  };

  db.collection('FlashCards').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
        renderDocList();
      }
    });
  });

  return <>{renderDocList()}</>;
};

export default AddCard;
```

But although the new data get added to FireStore collection but I cannot see any changes on the page. Still I have to refresh (reload) browser to see those changes.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would have approached it in a different way - why upload and then load again?

When onAdd is called save your data to set state, the change in state will re-render your component with the new data.

If you insist on going the save\load path then try using the use effect hook combined with set state as mentioned here:
https://dev.to/chantastic/connect-useeffect-and-usestate-to-update-components-with-data-4aaj

Lots of the power of React.js is in state, use it :)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is going to see the result of the `renderDocList` call in this snippet:

```
db.collection('FlashCards').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
  changes.forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === 'added') {
      renderDocList();
    }
  });
});
```

If you want the UI to update, you need to tell React that there is new data for it to render. And that's what `useState` hooks are used for. It don't fully see how your code affects what is being rendered, but you'll need some call to a setter that modifies the state that your component renders.

So say that your original text comes from the database, you'd do:

```
db.collection('FlashCards').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
  changes.forEach((change) => {
    if (change.type === 'added') {
      setNewOriginalText("new document added");
    }
  });
});
```

And that in turn will then rerender any components that display the original text.

Also see:

- [Can't fetch firebase collection with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561358/cant-fetch-firebase-collection-with-react/55561577#55561577), where I use `setState` instead of the `useState` hook.
- [NodeJs/Firestore/React- Storing Firestore query results into the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261301/nodejs-firestore-react-storing-firestore-query-results-into-the-state/55263110#55263110)