# React native call function in text element

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i want to call a `getName` function which takes a `game.set(Integer)` and `returns a String`.
This string i want to set inside the text element.
The function is working perfectly, I printed the results before returning.
Now, after importing the function `import { getName } from '../SetsAPI';`, the result I get after calling the function is always `undefined`.

Function call:

```
import { getName } from '../SetsAPI';
...
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Game: </Text>
          <View style={styles.questionAmount}>
               <Text>{getName(game.set)}</Text>
          </View>
     </View>
```

Function:

```
 export const getName = (setId)=>{
    console.log("setId: " + setId)
    setsRef
    .doc(setId)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("document name: " + doc.data().name)
        return doc.data().name;
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
  })
  }
```

Why does this happen? And how can I prevent it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `useState` to store the value, which then causes it to be updated in the UI.

First declare the state at:

```
{name, setName} = useState('');
```

This allows us to get `name` and call `setName`, and gives it an initial value of `''`.

Then in your `componentDidMount` or in a `useEffect` hook, you'll do:

```
setsRef
.doc(setId)
.get()
.then((doc) => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("document name: " + doc.data().name)
    setName(doc.data().name);
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
```

This causes your component to rerender itself, and then you can use the `name` property in your render method.

Also see:

- [React + Firestore : Return a variable from a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530492/react-firestore-return-a-variable-from-a-query/53530991#53530991)
- [NodeJs/Firestore/React- Storing Firestore query results into the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261301/nodejs-firestore-react-storing-firestore-query-results-into-the-state/55263110#55263110)
- [FireStore - Update the UI with new data without reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564922/firestore-update-the-ui-with-new-data-without-reloading-the-browser/62565104#62565104)