# exported array becomes a pending promise?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I have this code that gets all players in a specific lobby. The `console.log()` before the return works as expected:

```
  const getPlayersByLobby = async (lobbyId) => {
    const playersRef = firebase.firestore().collection("GameLobbies").doc(lobbyId).collection("players");
    const playerNames = [];
    const players = await playersRef.get();
    players.forEach((groupSnapshot) => {
       playerNames.push(groupSnapshot.data().name)
    });
    console.log(playerNames) // ["player1Name", "player2Name"];
    return playerNames
  }
```

Now when rendering the component I do a `console.log(getPlayersByLobby(lobby.id))` to see what I get. I see I have a pending promise instead of my array.

Can anyone help my why this is? And how to get my array back?

```
  return(
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Current game lobbies:</h1>
      {gameLobbies.map((lobby) => { //gameLobbies comes from a useState() hook that does work
        return (<div key={lobby.id}>
          <h2>naam: {lobby.name}</h2>
          <p>Code: {lobby.gameId}</p>
          <h3>Spelers in deze lobby:</h3>
          <ul>
            {console.log(getPlayersByLobby(lobby.id))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: try checking the typeof returned value and leave a comment about that

Comment: @codingwith3dv obviously, the result of an "unawaited" `async` function is a promise.

Comment: @codingwith3dv console.log(typeof(getPlayersByLobby(lobby.name))) actually showed this to be an object

Comment: Since `playerNames` is loaded asynchronously, you need to store its value in the state of the component. The simplest way to do that is through `useState` as Josh shows here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59959589 and I've shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67511632, and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62565426

Answer (score 2):

This is something I struggled with when I came across promises.

With promises it is important to remember that `async/await` is just a syntactic sugar and it is doesn't make the code synchronous as one might think. It lets you write your code in a way in which it **looks** synchronous.

Any `async` function by default returns a `Promise` and the only way to get the returned value (which comes AFTER the promise has resolved) is to `await` it **everywhere you call that `async` function**.

It does not matter that you already awaited it within the function, that doesn't mean that the function will wait for the promise to get the value/resolve the value before it returns.

The function simply returns the `Promise` right away with pending status and once the data is there the Promise is updated with the data. In this case by not adding `await` you are saying "I don't want to wait for the data, just give me the promise" and now you can pass this promise around but you will have to `await` it if you want the value anywhere you pass it.

Since in your example in the component `{console.log(getPlayersByLobby(lobby.id))}` there is no `await` before you call `getPlayersByLobby` it will simply return a pending `Promise` without **awaiting** it

Another way to think about it is using `.then(()=> {}).catch((error) => {})` syntax. If there were no `async/await` keywords or `Promise`s you would have to chain all `then`s inside of each other.

Using `async/await` you STILL have to chain the promise but it just looks more readable/synchronous

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

try to store players in the state when you get them from the database, also its better to use `useEffect` when you retrieve data from your database

```
const [players, setPlayers] = useState([])
const [lobbyId, setLobbyId] = useState([initalId])

 useEffect(async () => {
    const playersRef = 
  firebase.firestore().collection("GameLobbies").doc(lobbyId).collection("players");
    const playerNames = [];
    const players = await playersRef.get();
    players.forEach((groupSnapshot) => {
       playerNames.push(groupSnapshot.data().name)
    });
    console.log(playerNames) // ["player1Name", "player2Name"];
    //return playerNames
    setPlayers(playerNames)
  }, [lobbyId]) // it called again whenever you changed your looby id
```

now it should work

```
<ul>
   // now you have access to them
   {console.log(players)}
 </ul>
```

Comment: How would you give lobbyId as a parameter in a useEffect hook? Also does this work if there are multiple lobbies that all have unique players. Don't you dump all players in 1 players array?

Comment: oh!  sorry i missed this,  check the answer

Comment: ya it works with multiple lobbies once you change the `lobbyId` the ` useEffect` will run again with the updated lobby id and pull  different players

Answer (score 1):

First, as you are only using the `name` field stored in your document, consider switching out `groupSnapshot.data().name` for `groupSnapshot.get("name")` for efficiency.

As this function is stateless, you should place this function outside of your component's render function:

```js
const getPlayersByLobby = async (lobbyId) => {
    const playersRef = firebase.firestore()
        .collection("GameLobbies")
        .doc(lobbyId)
        .collection("players");
    const playerNames = [];
    const players = await playersRef.get();
    players.forEach((groupSnapshot) => {
        playerNames.push(groupSnapshot.get("name"))
    });
    console.log(playerNames) // ["player1Name", "player2Name"];
    return playerNames
}
```

Same with this "render lobby" function:

```js
const renderLobby = (lobby, playerList = undefined) {
  let players;

  if (playerList === undefined) {
    players = (<p key="loading">Loading player list...</p>);
  } else if (playerList === null) {
    players = (<p key="failed">Failed to get player list</p>);
  } else if (playerList.length === 0) {
    players = (<p key="empty">Player list empty</p>);
  } else {
    players = (<ul key="players">{
      playerList.map((p) => (
        <li key={p.id}>
          {p.name}
        </li>
      ))
    }</ul>);
  }
 
  return (
    <div key={lobby.id}>
      <h2>naam: {lobby.name}</h2>
      <p>Code: {lobby.gameId}</p>
      <h3>Spelers in deze lobby:</h3>
      { players }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Next, in your component, you make use of `useEffect()` to fetch data from the database. Here, I've used a state object that is a map of lobby IDs to lists of players. On each render, a call is sent off to the database to fetch the current player list.

Because Promises (in this case, database calls) can take longer than render cycles to finish, we need to make sure to not call any `setState` functions after the component has been unmounted. This is done using the `disposed` boolean value to discard the results of the Promises if the `useEffect`'s unsubscribe function has been called.

```js
const [gameLobbies, setGameLobbies] = useState(/* init value */);
const [playersByLobby, setPlayersByLobby] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
    let disposed = false;
 
    const newPlayersByLobby = {};

    Promise.all(gameLobbies.map((lobby) =>
      getPlayersByLobby(lobby.id)
        .then((playerList) => newPlayersByLobby[lobbyId] = playerList)
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(`Failed to get Lobby #${lobbyId}'s player list: `, err);
          newPlayersByLobby[lobbyId] = null;
        })
    ))
      .then(() => {
        if (disposed) return; // component disposed/gameLobbies was changed
        setPlayersByLobby(newPlayersByLobby);
      })
    
    return () => disposed = true;
}, [gameLobbies]); // rerun when gameLobbies updates

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Current game lobbies:</h1>
    {
      gameLobbies.map(
        (lobby) => renderLobby(lobby, playersByLobby[lobby.id])
      )
    }
  </div>
);
```

**Note:** Consider implementing a `<Lobby>` component along with a `<PlayerList>` component. By doing this, you allow yourself the ability to make full use of the Firestore's Realtime updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
{
  getPlayeesByLobby(lobby.id).then(val => {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

This should give an error in React so what's next

Make an iife or more specifically useEffect in React
so make a useState and after getting data from backend setPlayers to that array. And then map the array and render `<li>` in the `<ul>`.

This is what you need to do

Comment: pretty close,  I get the array I want when I do that. But react gives me this error now: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. Pretty weird since it is an array...